I'm having issue with react-native-audio-recorder-player
Task :react-native-audio-recorder-player:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
I've tried Deleting
node_modules
./gradlew clean
none of them is working. From last 2 days I trying any leads would be help.
